ANOVA Type III understanding
I stumbled across something very interesting to me earlier, in the question and answer here:
ANOVA type III strange results

I reiterate the warning I found in the function documentation, highlighting an important recommendation:
"Be careful of type-III tests: For a traditional multifactor ANOVA model with interactions, for example, these tests will normally only be sensible when using contrasts that, for different terms, are orthogonal in the row-basis of the model, such as those produced by contr.sum, contr.poly, or contr.helmert, but not by the default contr.treatment. In a model that contains factors, numeric covariates, and interactions, main-effect tests for factors will be for differences over the origin. In contrast (pun intended), type-II tests are invariant with respect to (full-rank) contrast coding. If you don't understand this issue, then you probably shouldn't use Anova for type-III tests."

Well, I definitely don't understand this issue, but I want to, so I am asking here: what are some good resources for learning about this issue ?
I understand the basics of of Anova and (a long time ago) I learned about manually computing susm of squares for Anova tests for designed factorial experiments, but I've forgotten all about that now. I've had a little exposure to different types of contrast, but the quoted passage from the documentation above, has me very confused. A few related questions:

why are these tests "only be sensible when using contrasts that, for different terms, are orthogonal in the row-basis of the model" ?
What is the "row basis" of the model ? I'm guessing it has something to do with the model matrix, but I have no idea what ?
What does "differences over the origin" mean ?
Why are Type-II tests "invariant with respect to contrast coding", while TYPE-III are not ?
What is it about contr.sum, contr.poly, and contr.helmert that is different to contr.treatment that makes them sensible for Type-III tests ?

As you can see, I basically don't understand anything about that passage.
What are some good resources for learning about this ? Good answers here will be much appreciated, and any book or book-chapter references would also be much appreciated.

The quoted passage you've come across highlights some important considerations when performing ANOVA, particularly regarding Type III sums of squares and the use of different contrast coding schemes. Here I will try to break down the concepts and address your questions.

Orthogonal Contrasts and Their Importance:


Orthogonal Contrasts: These are sets of contrasts (linear combinations of group means) that are uncorrelated. This means that the information each contrast provides about the differences between group means is unique and does not overlap with the information provided by other contrasts.

Derivation of Orthogonal Contrasts: Orthogonal contrasts are derived by ensuring that the sum of the products of the corresponding coefficients in each pair of contrasts equals zero. For example, if you have two contrasts, $C_1$ ande $C_2$, they are orthogonal if $\Sigma(c_{1i} \times c_{2i}) = 0$
are the coefficients for the $i$th level of the factor in each contrast. This process can involve techniques such as Gram-Schmidt orthogonalisation or using predefined orthogonal contrast schemes like Helmert or polynomial contrasts.

Why Orthogonality Matters: When contrasts are orthogonal, the sums of squares for each contrast can be interpreted independently of others. This independence is important for the interpretability of Type III tests in ANOVA, which assess the significance of each factor adjusted for the presence of all other factors in the model.



Row Basis of the Model:


Model Matrix: In ANOVA, the model matrix, $X$, represents the data in terms of predictors and (for categorical predictors) their levels. Each row corresponds to an observation, and each column corresponds to a predictor (main effects and interactions).
Row Basis: This refers to the span (the set of all possible linear combinations) of its rows. For contrasts to be orthogonal in the row-basis means that the contrasts should be uncorrelated when considering the data (as organised in the model matrix).


Differences Over the Origin:


This refers to comparing means or effects relative to the overall mean or baseline (the origin). In Type III ANOVA, the main effects are tested by comparing each level of a factor to the reference level, considering the presence and influence of other factors in the model. Type III ANOVA does not simply compare each level of a factor to the overall mean. Rather, it compares each level to a baseline (or reference) level while adjusting for the other factors in the model. The "adjustment" means that the presence of other factors and their levels are taken into account, isolating the effect of the factor of interest.


Invariance of Type II Tests to Contrast Coding:


Type II Tests: These tests evaluate each main effect after accounting for other main effects but not interactions. They are invariant to contrast coding because they do not partition the sums of squares into unique components attributable to interactions.
Type III Tests: These tests evaluate each main effect and interaction after accounting for all other effects in the model. The sums of squares are affected by the choice of contrasts, hence not invariant to contrast coding.


Contr.sum, Contr.poly, Contr.helmert vs. Contr.treatment:


Contr.sum (Sum-to-zero contrasts): Ensures that the sum of the contrasts for each factor level equals zero, maintaining orthogonality.
Contr.poly (Polynomial contrasts): Used for ordered factors, ensuring orthogonal polynomial contrasts.
Contr.helmert: Contrasts comparing each level to the mean of the subsequent levels, also orthogonal.
Contr.treatment (Default in R and several other statistics systems): Compares each level to a reference level, which does not ensure orthogonality and can lead to non-independence in the presence of interactions, making it less suitable for Type III tests.

Recommended Resources

"Applied Linear Statistical Models" by Kutner, Nachtsheim, Neter, and Li: This comprehensive book covers ANOVA, including the concepts of contrasts and different types of sums of squares.

"Applied Regression Analysis and Generalized Linear Models" by John Fox is particularly valuable for understanding the complexities of ANOVA and contrast coding as well as regression modelling in general.

"Design and Analysis of Experiments" by Douglas Montgomery: This book provides a solid foundation in the principles of experimental design and analysis, including ANOVA and contrasts.


References:
Fox, J. (2015). Applied regression analysis and generalized linear models. Sage publications.
Kutner, M. H., Nachtsheim, C. J., Neter, J., & Li, W. (2004). Applied linear statistical models (5th ed.). McGraw-Hill/Irwin.
Montgomery, D. C. (2019). Design and analysis of experiments (10th ed.). Wiley.
